# OpenCv & MCU (Arduino) capability

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, arduino, microcontroller

I have for the first time installed the OpenCV module for python3, and i am trying to find the best way to use OpenCV with a connected MCU (Microcontroller Unit) such as Arduino, or to control I/O of a Raspberry Pi 3..

In the past:
I have written a python GUI with `tkinter` and programmed the MCU to be controlled via serial communication. The MCU receives a string of data that is being written to the port. When I click a button in my python GUI, it then executes the programmed functions.

[image: Tk GUI]

I have then also turned the host computer into a web server, and have written a front end using HTML/CSS/JavaScript, more specifically using `AJAX`, which then makes a call to a PHP back end script that in turn executes a python script(could use bash script), which is sending commands to a MCU.
(Yes it's secure. And mildly confusing to most people.)

[image: HTML front end, using AJAX/PHP/Python to control relays etc.]

In saying that, I have had some time to have a play around with some examples of OpenCV, but it has been quite difficult finding documentation that is clear and gives me an idea of how to use the module within robotics/mechatronics and industrial automation projects. All the uses I have seen have been mentioned using Arduino and processing.

So my question after explaining this is, how do I start using OpenCV object/face recognition and have it send commands serially?
Is Arduino processing the only option or can this be achieved with just the python modules and the code embedded on the MCU?

Thank you in advance to anyone who may be able to give me some guidance.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS](http://www.instructables.com/id/Face-detection-and-tracking-with-Arduino-and-OpenC/)

Comment: Thanks, i have had a look at the information mentioned above, but as most of the examples i have found do, it assumes the use of windows and arduino IDE exclusively.  So to be more specific, what would i need to do/change in order to make this work in a kind of universal sense within GNU/Linux using the python module, and any arbitrary MCU?

Comment: I noticed in amongst the information i have collected, that there is examples of code/projects that output X/Y coordinates to the screen, would this be a case of modifying the code/ adding to it, to write x and y coordinates to the serial port as they are being written to the screen, then interpreting the coordinates on the MCU to control things such as pan/tilt ?